# Останавливается действие бота aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.req)
async def process_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print("Все ок")
        await message.answer(f"""Супер ! Ваш заказ уже в обработке . Срок выполнения заказа - до 5 рабочих дней . Перед доставкой на данный адрес с вами свяжется курьер. Оплата за доставку производится по тарифу Яндекс и оплачивается получателем .""")
        await message.answer(f"""Оставьте пожалуйста отзыв в наших соцсетях :""")
        data["completed_image_data"] = " "
        data['location'] = message.text
        data["ID"] = message.from_user.id
        data["UserName"] = message.from_user.full_name
        data_ready = {
    'name': data['name'],
    'number': data['number'],
    'choice': data['choice'],
    'size': data['size'],
    'color': data['color'],
    'description': data['description'],
    'description_translated': data['description_translated'],
    'image url': data['saved_image_url'],
    'location': data['location'],
    'id': data['ID'],
    'username': data['UserName']
}
        print("Все ок 2")
        await bot.send_message(CONSTANT_USER_ID, f"""
Имя - {data_ready['name']}
Номер - {data_ready['number']}
Выбор - {data_ready['choice']}
Размер - {data_ready['size']}
Цвет - {data_ready['color']}
Местоположение - {data_ready['location']}
ID - {data_ready['id']}
Имя пользователя - {data_ready['username']}
""")
        print("Все ок 3")
        photo = Image.open(data['description_translated'] + 'var.jpg')
        scale_factor = 4.0
        result = upscale('Lanczos', photo, scale_factor)
        result.save(data['description_translated'] + 'var1.jpg')
        document = data['description_translated'] + 'var1.jpg'
        print("Все ок 4")
        await bot.send_document(CONSTANT_USER_ID,document=document)



        print("Все ок 5")



        x = [[i for i in data_ready.values()]]

        print(x)

        wks.append_table(x, start='A2', end=None,
                            dimension='ROWS', overwrite=False)
        os.remove(data['description_translated'] + '.jpg')
        os.remove(data['description_translated'] + 'var.jpg')
        print(data)
        await state.finish()
```

Я сделал проверку на каком месте он останавливается.

```
Все ок
Все ок 2
Все ок 3
Все ок 4
```

Останавливается до того как отправить документ конкретному пользователю.
Не понимаю почему так

Answer (score 0):

```
        print("Все ок 3")
        photo = Image.open(data['description_translated'] + 'var.jpg')
        scale_factor = 4.0
        result = upscale('Lanczos', photo, scale_factor)
        result.save(data['description_translated'] + 'var1.jpg')
        document = data['description_translated'] + 'var1.jpg'
        document_path = data['description_translated'] + 'var1.jpg'
        document_input_file = InputFile(document_path)

        await bot.send_document(CONSTANT_USER_ID, document=document_input_file)
```

https://aiogram-birdi7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram/bot.html?highlight=send_document#aiogram.bot.bot.Bot.send_document

не правильно давал документ